# GParted live hangs on Debian info screen

Tags: gparted

I'm attempting to increase the size of my Ubuntu root drive. It was suggested to create a live USB of GParted to merge the free space I've created into the root drive. I created said USB, but when I go through the options (the first GParted live option, not touching keymaps, language, and video option), I see a screen on which there are some very fast messages about something nvidia not loading, and some other files I can't identify. Then I get to a view explaining it's Debian and the Debian disclaimer, and then nothing. It hangs on said view. I can hit keys and I can see them appear under the messaging, but otherwise I'm stuck.

Answer (score 0):

Faced the same issue and fixed it by visiting [this page](https://gparted.org/display-doc.php%3Fname%3Dgparted-live-manual#gparted-live-tips-on-booting-gparted-live).

Your issue can be different from mine (please read the page), but what worked for me: on boot, instead of selecting "GParted Live (Default settings)", I selected "Other modes of GParted Live" and "GParted Live (Safe graphic settings, vga=normal)".